# Facebook SDK reference in Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I try to add Facebook SDK to android project. I tried add Facebook reference in eclipse to my project in "Java Build Path -> Projects" and "Project Reference". Eclipse see this library, but when run app on my phone get error:

```
12-30 11:55:02.198: E/AndroidRuntime(3144): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
```

Facebook login button in my layout

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
 android:id="@+id/buttonMain_loginFacebook"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

I added Facebook reference to my project in Properties->Android but when I open Properties again I see the red cross next to the Facebook reference.

Before I added Facebook SDK to another project all was fine.

**Fix:** When open Facebook SDK project, helps copy to workspace.

Comment: @user3075488: it's great that you're trying to improve posts, but please don't use `code spans` to highlight ordinary words -- code spans should be used for keywords or variables in code that is used within a sentence. For example, the following sentence is acceptable: "_If you don't want your code to run at all, use a `while` loop instead._" However, you shouldn't do something like: "_I am attempting to use `iOS Objective C Platform` to develop, anyone know how?_" Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

copy facebook jar file from the `facebooksdk/bin` directory and put it in your projects `libs` folder. And add it as external jar file from `buildpath->configure build path -> libraries -> add external jars`

Comment: All looks like before when i don't add Facebook SDK